# Mysqldump keeps having an uknown variable error

Tags: mysql, variables, dump

My dump code:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin> mysqldump -uroot -p marketingfunctions --single-transaction=TRUE > C:\20130404.sql
```

The error:

> mysqldump: unknown variable 'set-variable=max_allowed_packet=16M'

The image path:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56
```

In that my.ini file I've checked for the phrase `'set-variable=max_allowed_packet=16M'` with no avail.

Any idea how to get around this or what could be going on?

Comment: Hm, you can start it with `--no-defaults` as the _first_ parameter I believe, but there is a my.ini / my.cnf _somewhere_ that sets it...

Comment: That worked! You rock